# Wide open K8S Firewall Rule being created out of nowhere?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

Using Terraform -> Helm -> GKE on Google Cloud

It looks like a firewall rule is being created for each of my services
[image]

I'm not creating this rule manually anywhere in my configuration. Is this something GKE is configuring when it deploys my app? I'd like to remove / correct this rule as I don't want wide open ingress for all of my services. Where should I start looking?

Comment: Can you please share the deployment file/code you are using when creating the GKE cluster?

Comment: I suggest you check the Helm chart and see if there's config to disable ingress.

Answer (score 1):

I wanna help you with this question about where the mentioned firewall rule come from.

[GKE creates firewall rules automatically when creating the following resources:](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/firewall-rules)

**GKE clusters**

**GKE Services**

**GKE Ingresses**

### [GKE creates the following ingress firewall rules when creating a Service.](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/firewall-rules#service-fws)

Name: k8s-fw-[loadbalancer-hash]

Purpose: Permits ingress traffic to reach a Service.

Source: **Specified in the Service manifest.** Defaults to 0.0.0.0/0 (any source)

Destination: Node tag

Protocol and ports: **TCP and UDP on the ports specified in the Service manifest.**

[GKE creates the following ingress firewall rules when creating an Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/firewall-rules#ingress-fws)

[GKE creates the following ingress firewall rules when creating a cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/firewall-rules#cluster-fws)

### I hope this information solve your question about the nature of the mentioned firewall rule